# How to format procfile to call a program in a folder?

Tags: heroku, procfile

In the Procfile, `worker: node bot.js` works fine, but if I move the file in a folder, then how would I format it? I would think something like `worker: node folder/bot.js` but I don't know. Thanks to anyone who responds.

Comment: "I would think something like worker: node folder/bot.js but I dont know"—did you _try_ that?

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
worker: node folder/bot.js
```

or

```
worker: cd folder && node bot.js
```

In some cases it does make a difference how you are calling it but it depends on your program.